# dojo addOnLoad/ready does not work with dialogs

Tags: dojo

So it appears the `dojo.addOnLoad` and `dojo.ready` functions do not apply to dialogs.

I am looking for alternatives.  The trouble is my dialog HTML is dynamically created and contains many different script blocks each using a `dojo.connect` function to add functionality. For example, I have:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='value(liquid40011252)'  value='1' dojoType='dijit.form.CheckBox' id='liquid4001125249' />
 <script type='text/javascript'>dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
    dialogConnect4001125249();});
    function dialogConnect4001125249() { 
        dojo.connect(dijit.byId('liquid4001125249'), 'onChange', 
         function(){
           // my code for toggling checkboxes ets
         });
    }
  </script>
```

This works fine in a normal webpage but with the dialog the `addOnLoad` is not respected and `dijit.byId('liquid4001125249')` is undefined. `ready` does not help.

I instantiate the dialog with

```
searchDlg = dojox.widget.DialogSimple();
searchDlg.set("title", title);
searchDlg.set("style", "width: " + width + "px; max-height: "+height+"px; overflow:auto;");
searchDlg.set("content", content);
searchDlg.show();
```

and considered calling the `dialogConnect` after `show` but there are many `dialogConnectxxxxx` and I do not have the list.

Perhaps an alternative is to somehow add the list of `dialogConnect`s somewhere - perhaps on the dialog itself.  Not sure.

Any ideas on how to solve this complex problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, dialogs exist only after the `searchDlg...` code is executed. It is normal that `dijit.byId` does not find them in the `addOnLoad` routine.

I don't really know what you wanna do in the `connectDialog` functions but I think you will gain in readability by subclassing Dialog and use the `postCreate` method to connect to the dialog.

```
dojo.declare("mynamespace.MyCustomDialog", [dijit.Dialog], {

    templateString: dojo.cache("mynamespace", "templates/MyCustomDialog.html"),
    widgetsInTemplate: true,

    postCreate: function()
        {
        // do whatever dojo.connect you need
        },

    });
```